# Automatically add a row to similar table in sheet-2 if I add it to the main table in sheet-1

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following table in sheet-1 from an excel workbook. I want an excel formula that can allow me to automatically add a row to similar table in sheet-2 if I add it to the main table in sheet-1.

Example: If I add a row with the name "Jane" in sheet-1 it should automatically be added to similar table in sheet-2.

```
Name    Hours   Rate    Total
jhon    35  10  350
David   20  11  220
Mark    50  12  600
Hellen  40  11  440
Iren    40  13  520
Nicole  39  14  546
```

Comment: Would you be open to a VBA solution? With just formulas, sheet-2 needs to start out larger than you expect sheet-1 to ever be. Formulas can't expand a table automatically.

Comment: Would you please tell me what should I do to make it work?

Comment: To make it work with formulas or VBA? It's a time commitment to to make up an example and I don't want to spend it doing both. What have you already tried? Is your data in an actual table (Insert ribbon > Table) or is it just a block of data? Do both tables have exactly the same number of rows? Is there anything else on the sheet or is it purely a data sheet (which is better)?

Comment: Yes it's just a block of data, and they have exact same number of rows

Comment: Formulas (big starting table) or VBA (messier)? Anything else on the sheet?

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of [try to fix my Excel formula](https://superuser.com/q/885520/150988) — I guess; it’s hard to tell, but the data are identical.  The OP (1) doesn’t even seem to understand the vocabulary of Excel (see the comments under [Engineer Toast’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/884617/150988#884695), and (2) hasn’t been here since March 10 ’15 (a week after the questions were asked).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the VBA solution.

1) Open VBA Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)

2) Double click on the sheet object in the Project Explorer window on the left (it has a tree structure)

3) Paste this code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    If TypeName(Target) = "Range" Then
        If LenB(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value) > 0 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
                If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row = UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
                    If UsedRange.Rows.Count > Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
                        For Each cell In Target.Cells
                            If Not Intersect(cell, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = cell.Value
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set cell = Nothing
End Sub
```

4) Change values as you need to. The most important ones are as follows:
  4.1) `Range("A:A")` Change to be wherever the `Name` column is if it's not on column `A`.
  4.2) `Sheet2` Change to be the VBA code name of the worksheet where you want the values to be copied. The code name is what appears in that tree on the left side of the VBA Editor. By default, it's things like `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc. (It's the same as the tab name defaults but without the space.)

Key Point: This only adds rows. It does not delete them as you delete things on sheet-1. You can do that but I try to avoid deleting things in VBA unless I'm really sure because you can't easily undo that operation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Should I add this code to the master sheet1 or to the sheet2. And yes ColumnA contains Names, ColumnB contains Hours, ColumnC contains Rate, and ColumnD contains Total. Thank you again

Comment: I changed the Range to Range("A2:A7")) in sheet1, but it didnt work. I had this highlighted in yellow:     If LenB(Target.Value) > 0 Then

Comment: I bet it was a type mismatch error when you edited more than one cell at once. I'll update the answer to account for mass deletion or copy/paste.

Comment: So what should I do now? I am sorry, but I am confused as I am not into much excel :(

Comment: Delete the code you copied before. Copy & paste the new code from my updated answer.

Comment: it worked, but when I added one row under Hellen name. It was added automatically in sheet2 but under Nicole name?!

Comment: Every time you add a name to sheet1, it copies that name to the end of sheet2. This completely meets the original question. Do you want to only add values to sheet2 if they aren't already in that list? That's a different request.

Comment: what I meant by my original question is to copy the whole row under the same spot. Example: if I add the whole row with name of "Jane" under "David" row in Master sheet1, the whole row (named Jane) should be automatically added under "David" row in sheet2

Comment: Are you copying and pasting entire rows of data or are you adding them manually? That's a big difference. You'll want to change the VBA to copy the entire row at once instead of the cell-by-cell copy that it does now. Do some research on how to do that. I'm out of the office the rest of the week so I won't be back on here.

Comment: I add them manually in master sheet1. Even if I do my research I cannot figure this out because all this formulas are too complicate me for me to grasp

Comment: Here's a better solution, then: Make sheet2 be a table. Every column except the first is a lookup formula to extract data from sheet1 based on the value in column `A`. (I like the [INDEX / MATCH](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) combination for lookups.) This code adds values to column `A` in sheet2, the formulas automatically copy down because it's a table, and that means that sheet2 will fill in as you fill in sheet1.

Comment: to be frank with you I didn't understand a word from what you said. those codes are ambiguous to me as I am not professional in excel

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have the time to invest in this and I have no means to share files while at work. Try these searches to get you started: excel table, excel index match lookup

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You have been very patient with me and I really appreciate that